# JavaScript - this inside of timeout with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why isn't `this` inside of the `setTimeout` equal to the object that invoked the render function when using arrow functions?

```
 class X {
      constructor(config) {
        this.data = config.data;
        this.render_ = config.render;
      }
      render() {
        this.render_(this.data);
      }
    }
    var x = new X({
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      render: (data) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this);
        }, 200);
      }
    });
    x.render();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the part of the [arrow function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that says "Arrow functions used as methods"

in summary: arrow functions just simply do not bind `this` or their own version of `this`, but rather references the global Window object.

Comment: This question appears to be about `this`, not `arguments`.

Comment: updated @FelixKling I was looking at the section above :')

Answer (score 3):

Because [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are *lexically* bound. That means they take on the value of "this" at the time of declaration. They are not affected by other means of modifying the `this` value, including being called as a method or functions like [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```js
function F() {
  this.type = 'F';
  this.logTypeExpression = function() {
    console.log(this.type);
  };
  this.logTypeArrow = () => {
    console.log(this.type);
  };
}

function G() {
  this.type = 'G';
}

var f = new F();
var g = new G();

f.logTypeExpression(); // F
f.logTypeArrow(); // F

// Now lets give these functions to G
g.logTypeExpression = f.logTypeExpression;
g.logTypeArrow = f.logTypeArrow;

g.logTypeExpression(); // G
g.logTypeArrow(); // F(!) (That's because `this` was assigned by the arrow function)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time that the arrow function is created, `this` isn't bound to any object, so it still refers to `window`. Maybe you want to try `console.log(x);` if you want to refer to that specific instance?

Comment: This should be a comment, at best. The issue is that `this` does not refer to the `x` object.

Answer (score 0):

The code below only holds a reference to the function you created using an object literal syntax.

```
this.render_ = config.render;
```

Using *bind(this)* will tell the function to use the parameter object as the this reference when calling the function in the instance of your X object.

```
class X {
    constructor(config) {
        this.data = config.data;
        this.render_ = config.render.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        this.render_(this.data);
    }
}
```

Also, it does not matter if it's an arrow function or a regular function expression in your code snippet.